# Magento2: Custom ExtensionAttributes for Customer_Address not saved into database

Tags: magento2, customer-address, extension-attributes

I am stuck. I hope someone had already solved my problem. The magento docu does not help me any further.

I added some new ExtensionAttributes for Customer_Address entity. These fields are correctly displaying in checkout. 
For the customer address edit view I have overwritten the template of the `customer_address_edit` block.

In both cases the Post data is not saved into the database. No errors given, not system.log neither exception.log or any exception.

In `Magento\Customer\Controller\AddressMagento\Customer\Controller\Address\FormPost` seem to be some operations that will merge data columns of the customer_address_entity with extensions_attributes or custom_attributes.
Some debugging shows me, that my extensions_attributes are recognized here.

But somehow the data get lost on its way to the database.
To sum up my little module: I did mostly the same things as Bartlomiejsz in the of 27.Feb comment on this post: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6575

Answer (score 0):

Use this `InstallData.php` script to add attribute for `customer_address`

```
$customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

$customerSetup->addAttribute('customer_address', 'suburb', [
    'label' => 'Suburb',
    'input' => 'text',
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'source' => '',
    'required' => false,
    'position' => 70,
    'visible' => true,
    'system' => false,
    'is_used_in_grid' => false,
    'is_visible_in_grid' => false,
    'is_filterable_in_grid' => false,
    'is_searchable_in_grid' => false,
    'backend' => ''
]);


$attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer_address', 'suburb')
    ->addData(['used_in_forms' => [
        'adminhtml_customer_address',
        'customer_address_edit',
        'customer_register_address'
    ]]);
$attribute->save();

$salesSetup = $this->salesSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
$salesSetup->addAttribute('order_address', 'suburb', ['type' => 'text']);
$quoteSetup = $this->quoteSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
$quoteSetup->addAttribute('quote_address', 'suburb', ['type' => 'text']);
}

$setup->endSetup();
```

Create `fieldset.xml` in etc folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:DataObject/etc/fieldset.xsd">
    <scope id="global">
        <fieldset id="sales_convert_quote_address">
             <field name="suburb">
                  <aspect name="to_order_address" />
             </field>
        </fieldset>
    </scope>
</config>
```

Override `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address` to set getter/setter methods:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Model\Order;

use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\RegionInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderAddressInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Model\AbstractModel;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Address\AddressModelInterface;

/**
 * Sales order address model
 *
 * @method \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Address _getResource()
 * @method \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Address getResource()
 * @method \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface getCustomerAddressData()
 * @method Address setCustomerAddressData(\Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface $value)
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessivePublicCount)
 */
class Address extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address
{
    public function getSuburb($suburb)
    {
         return $this->getData('suburb', $suburb);
    }

    public function setSuburb($suburb)
    {
         return $this->setData('suburb', $suburb);
    }
}
```

`di.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
  <preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address" type="<<VendorName>\<ModuleName>\Model\Order\Address"/>
</config>
```

> > Note: You have to place your attribute into checkout_index_index.xml or checkout onepage xml file.

Feel Free to ask!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, unfortunately it is not working yet. What do you mean by your note? Does it mean, even if I added my attribtues through "addAttribute in the Install Model and added in the fieldset.xml I still have to add it in the checkout_index_index.xml?

Comment: Yes you have to add the attribute in address form

Comment: I currently try to save the data that comes from my custom_attributes in customer_address edit view. The data is successfully passed through the objects, which I can see in Customer Address Model updateData method. But the data is not saved into DB. I think my attributes are not setup correctly. What items do I have to put Into eav value for used_in_forms to save the data in this view?

Comment: You can create an attribute as ''system' => true,`